# How to validate GitHub is communicating with OpenShift cartridge running Jenkins?

Tags: github, jenkins, openshift

I have a GitHub hook for a new check-in, but it is not being received by Jenkins (running on a RedHat OpenShift cartridge).

### Setup

- RedHat OpenShift cartridge running Jenkins
- Jenkins plugins in-play

  - GitHub plugin v1.8
  - Github Authentication plugin v0.14
  - Jenkins GIT client plugin v1.4.5
  - Jenkins GIT plugin v2.0
- Public GitHub repository

### Debugging

I have narrowed it down specifically to GitHub communicating with OpenShift, but am unsure how to troubleshoot any further, or resolve the issue. To narrow it down, I performed the following steps:

1. Configured one of each of the following types of Service Hooks in GitHub and captured the results in RequestBin

   - WebHook URL
   - Jenkins GitHub Plugin
   - Jenkins Git Plugin
2. I then ran Test Hook from GitHub
3. I took the resultant headers and payload from each RequestBin and manually created a POST request in Fiddler, pointing to the webhook endpoint
4. I saw some action on Jenkins by logging against *com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook*

However, the Test Hook from GitHub and checking into the repository never reached the server, at least not as evidenced by the logs.

I believe I have narrowed it down to an SSL issue. GitHub will not post the webhook to an OpenShift configured Jenkins cartridge, because it only responds to SSL/HTTPS. I am not sure of the specifics of how the canned Jenkins cartridge is configured, or how to change whether or not it uses SSL.

It is possible to change whether or not the OpenShift cartridge uses SSL, but I did not want to spend the time to get into it. The solution is to create your own cartridge definition, where you can specify all the settings, specifically which endpoints get created. [Here is the OpenShift reference](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#exposing-services-tcp-endpoints) to generate the proper endpoints in case anyone wants to go that route.

Comment: Do you know what port is being used to communicate with Jenkins on OpenShift? Also, did you install Jenkins or are you using the OpenShift Jenkins option?

Comment: I do not know which port is being used to communicate with Jenkins on OpenShift. The URL is https://<app-id>-<domain>.rhcloud.com/. I did not install Jenkins - I am using the pre-build OpenShift Jenkins cartridge.

Using Fiddler, it fails if I specify HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: Instead of RequestBin you should use Runscope (yes, yes, shameless plug) then you wouldn't have to re-issue from Fiddler. You can do taht right from our interface.

Comment: If you have an answer you should post it as such, not as an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have narrowed it down to an SSL issue. GitHub will not post the webhook to an OpenShift configured Jenkins cartridge, because it only responds to SSL/HTTPS. I am not sure of the specifics of how the canned Jenkins cartridge is configured, or how to change whether or not it uses SSL.

It is possible to change whether or not the OpenShift cartridge uses SSL, but I did not want to spend the time to get into it. The solution is to create your own cartridge definition, where you can specify all the settings, specifically which endpoints get created. Here is the OpenShift reference to generate the proper endpoints in case anyone wants to go that route.